# vim undo (delete) characters written by an imap!

Tags: vim

in vim, is there a way i can delete a block of text written by a i(no)remap, or an iab?
for example, say i have

> inoremap xx \hat{x}

in my .vimrc file, I want to be able to delete \hat{x} with one-two keystrokes (but not ^w or dB .. I could have two consecutive iabs consisting of just text, so I need to be able to cut abababcdcdcd in the middle, if cdcdcd is an iab of, say, "cc")

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Finally a clean solution**

```
inoremap xx ^Gu\hat{x}^Gu
```

(That's <kbd>C-g</kbd> there)

No more strange effects. You can even choose whether you want to isolate the undo item at both ends or just at the start (leave the trailing `^Gu` if you don't mind the hat-x being undone together with what came after it)

Now the salvaging info I used was, finally, trivial:

```
:he undo|/break/;+3p
```

Output:

> To do the opposite, break a change into two undo blocks, in Insert mode use
>   CTRL-G u.  This is useful if you want an insert command to be undoable in
>   parts.  E.g., for each sentence.  |i_CTRL-G_u|

Comment: sorry, this produces an even funnier result.. and the equivalent one, although it seems to work fine, if I type xx, then yy, then <Esc>u and then xx again, it redisplays the result of xx yy , not just xx !!!!

Comment: ugh - thanks for the feedback. It's like I feared then ("might have strange effects with branched history") only worse: a single branch is enough to make it misbehave. I'll see if I can work something out over the next 10 minutes :)

Comment: You won't believe it, but I did it! It was really simple, and involves no more hackery (just more RTFM - <shame/>). Ok, 19 minutes, but I was interrupted on the phone. Feel free to accept this answer after you convinced yourself :)

Comment: this is great! I ve given up on solutions not needing to re-adjust all my imaps, so this is the next best thing indeed! thumbs up!

Comment: and you. I love learning those corners of Vim that I was previously unaware of (most of the time)

Answer (score 1):

As the undo undoes the last insert, I frequently place a `<Esc>a` in the beginning of my mappings.

For example:

```
inoremap xx <Esc>a\hat{x}
```

Makes you leave and came back to insert mode so the undo can work properly. If you mistyped it, you can undo correctly.

I know this can be ugly and non-sense, but works. I'd love to know if there is a better solution to "flush" the undo.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I was hoping I would get away with it without changing my current imaps (i have a few!!). I m leaving it open for a while in case an answer that leaves them unchanged does what I want!

Comment: btw this doesn't work! I still get the same result! Maybe something wrong in my vimrc?

Comment: Aha, it didn't... Updating my answer with a 'hack' workaround that works!

Comment: @sfranky, that's strange. It works perfectly here. A mapping is just a keystroke, so if you type a bit, press `<Esc>`, `a`, insert a mapping, press `<Esc>` again and then `u` to undo, the mapping is removed, right?

Comment: when i do it like that yes, but when i put <Esc>a in a mapping, it just goes ahead and deletes the whole block of edits.

Comment: @sfranky even stranger! I'm sorry but I really make no idea on what can be influencing this. The only option which I think that can affect this is `nocompatible`, but I'm not sure if it has any effect here. By the way, I'm using MacVim 7.3, if this helps.

Comment: disabling nocompatible brings other problems, so I'd rather keep that! My vimrc admittedly is a bit dirty though, so there might be something interfering inside..